# Changing color of placeholder text in my <textarea> for my ionic 2 application

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

> placeholder is red in color before i enter text into it , i want my placeholder to stay in default color

[refering to this answer](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-ion-textarea-resize-height-dynamically/80885/3)

> HTML

```
<textarea  #myInput id="myInput" rows="1"  placeholder="Enter Question here" maxLength="100" (keyup)="resize()"  [(ngModel)]="addQuestion">
    </textarea>
```

> SCSS file

```
#myInput {
width: calc(100% - 10px);
border: 0;
border-radius: 0;
background: transparent;
}
```

> ts file

```
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: ElementRef;
   resize() {
    this.myInput.nativeElement.style.height = this.myInput.nativeElement.scrollHeight + 'px';
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2610741/4229270

Comment: @Sinto the link you provided is working fine with websites as per different browsers , but for mobile android application it was not applicable

Comment: ` #myInput id="myInput"`  what is this..?

Comment: @Edison #myInput is defined in ts file to expand text area according to length of text entered , and id="myInput" is defined in scss file for css part

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic uses [autoprefixer](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-app-scripts) in its build process.

you could use the psuedo-element `::placeholder`. Try

```
 #myInput::placeholder{
    color:red
 }
```